# When are comments "too much", and when are they not enough?

Tags: comments, coding-style

There is an on-going minor debate where I work about the efficacy of comments within code. One of the leads instructed his developers not to use comments as they are too "old fashioned", and a couple of other developers indicated that they never use comments because they feel all they do is clutter up the code.

I have always pretty much adhered to the practice that I comment the top of every file with a basic comment block, comment each method/class/etc definition, and then I comment any place in the code where I think I might come back in 6 months and think to myself, "WTF".

Clearly this is subjective, but I'm curious to know if anyone has any really good arguments or experiences for one way or the other.

Comment: where I work we are advised not to use comments inside code, except for TODO comments. This helps writing clear code.

Comment: @Alexandre - I would argue that it doesn't help writing clear code, it just makes someone else's unclear code complete gibberish. The presence or lack of comments doesn't alter the code that's written.

Comment: @Joel: the rationale is that function names and code structure should make comments useless.

Comment: "I might come back in 6 months and think to myself, "WTF"" - Quite possibly an indication that the code isn't descriptive enough and could do with refactoring. It's only a rule of thumb and not a dogma, but with my own code, if I think I might wonder "WTF" in the future, someone else in the company will thing the same right now. Again, this is where I'd refactor.

Comment: @Jamie Dixon - tru dat, but I have had examples where the code was that jacked simply because it was coded exactly to the business requirement (financial computation usually), and without seeing the requirement in front of me, sometimes the calculations get the better of me when looking at it again later. Another dirty habit of mine when faced with something like that is to write the name of the requirements document, section, etc that dictated the crazy code so I can at least know where to look it up again.

Comment: *Many* duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432/commenting-code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922/do-you-comment-your-code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163600/when-not-to-comment-code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111563/whats-the-golden-code-comment-ratio, etc.

Answer (score 26):

I'll just point you to [Jeff Atwood's wonderful post on the subject](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/coding-without-comments.html), which hits the nail right on the head.

Comment: A - Thanks for the linked article. It was a good read.

Comment: @Joel - you're welcome, Jeff sums up the issue very nicely.

Comment: Ugh. He undermines his own point with his square root example; when he changes it to a "self documenting code" style he loses the information that the algorithm is Newton-Raphson approximation. Good identifiers and good comments work together.

Comment: A better post on this subject from Steve Yegge: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/02/portrait-of-n00b.html

Answer (score 25):

In all my career, I have never come across that wonderful beast "self-documenting code". Maybe I've just been unlucky, but I'm beginning to suspect it doesn't actually exist.

Comment: I have seen it, in 2012. I was working at Atlassian on the core platform code and I was thinking "Wow, I like this code, but that architect put no comments in the code, probably because he used his seniority to... avoid respecting the guidelines or something? But I understand how it works, so maybe I'm a hacker like him." Then the reason hit me: The methods had the right name, variables were self-explanatory and code paths were simple. I just didn't know how much experience it would take me to reach the same simplicity.

Answer (score 16):

Every once in a while I run across code that is so elegantly partitioned, has such compellingly obvious method, field and variable names that everything I need to know is obvious from the code.

In the general case, only really great code gurus write such code. The rest of us cobble together something that works.

- If you're a really great code guru, don't bother sullying your divine code with superfluous comments.
- If you barely know what you're doing, be careful to document your blundering attempts so others can try to salvage the mess.
- If you're average (and most of us are, sort of by definition) then leave some hints in comments for yourself and others to make things easier at maintenance time, but don't insult anyone's intelligence and waste space by documenting the REALLY obvious. Ideally, your comments should describe your code at a meta-level, indicating not what you're doing but why. Also how, if you're doing something unusual or tricky.

Comment: "It is one of the essential features of such incompetence that the person so afflicted is incapable of knowing that he is incompetent. To have such knowledge would already be to remedy a good portion of the offense." http://gagne.homedns.org/~tgagne/contrib/unskilled.html

Comment: Kruger-Dunning! I was looking for that. @sarnold: Thanks! :)

Comment: @Carl - A different question I suppose would be, have you ever found yourself commenting for the lowest common denominator? What defines the "meta-level" (in your opinion) that a group should comment code at?

Comment: @Joel: I try to consistently comment for the "middle." My comments explain the overall approach and anything that isn't obvious (or would require digging in other resources or such). I also comment fields (but not getters/setters!) where the name doesn't make it obvious what's in them.

Comment: There is a truth to this, but the Achille's Heel is that no one is any good at assessing their own skill level.

Answer (score 7):

"One of the leads instructed his developers not to use comments as they are too "old fashioned", and a couple of other developers indicated that they never use comments because they feel all they do is clutter up the code."

If I ever heard a developer I was working with talk like this, I would correct them. If I didn't have the necessary rank to correct them, I would leave the job.

Very clearly written code, with good identifiers -- the stuff sometimes referred to as 'self-documenting' -- does a fine job of illustrating what the code is doing. That's fine as far as it goes. The job of the comments is to explain **why**.

Comment: fortunately I don't work in either of the sections of these developers. On my team, the first thing defined was our standards document for code project (including comments). Casual discussion of our standards document "in-house" is what brought up the debate between the groups.

Answer (score 5):

This topic tends to be discussed a lot, but here are my US$0.02 on the subject:

1. I would rather see too many comments than not enough. Failing at anything, you can always delete superfluous comments from the code; however, you can not derive meaning from them if there are none there to begin with.
2. I've heard some developers argue that other developers that "over document" (definitions of this vary by person) their code are not good developers. While saying that you are updating a counter might be a sign that you don't know what you are doing, having a clear guide to some of the business logic sitting there in the middle of the method you are working on can be quite useful.
3. While there are some excellent developers out there that can write extremely clear code that doesn't require comments, most developers aren't that good or they spend more time writing the code to be self documenting than they would if they had just included a couple comments.
4. You don't know the skill level of the next person to read your code and if the language constructs you are using might be confusing it is usually a good idea to include a comment that someone can use to Google a tutorial with.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with comments is that they tend to stay long after the code that was commented has changed or even been deleted.

As a rule of thumb I'd only comment public API and difficult to understand algorithms.

Don't use comments to explain what you did - that's what the code is for, use comments to explain why you did it.

Comment: Strongly suggest writing your responses in a tool that provides spell-check capability.

Comment: And maybe grammar too... "Don't us commnet ot explain what you did" is like one of the future-will-have-been-past tenses from Hitch Hikers' Guide.

Comment: @sarnold, the SO editor spell checks for me, maybe he didn't notice the red underlines???

Comment: I took pity on the post and fixed the language.

Comment: @carl Smotricz, I hadn't noticed the 'edit' link, thanks; I took pity on the post and fixed the broken idiom. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Diomidis Spinellis](http://www.spinellis.gr/) just wrote a nice column for IEEE column ([quoted on his blog](http://www.spinellis.gr/blog/20100711/)), outlining the problem, and a few solutions:

> When commenting, we’re always a couple
>   of keystrokes away from disaster:
>   restating the code’s function in
>   English. And that’s when problems
>   start.

Answer (score 0):

One should write comment before the code or before the function so that next time looking at the function he/she can know immediately what was the purpose of that code.
It is happened to me many times that I write the code and then forgot the purpose of that. so, I make habit of writing comment before code.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd like to see in the comments is an explanation why a method that is obvious and much simpler than the method used in the code doesn't work.